# why SpeechSynthesisUtterance is not working on Chrome

Tags: text-to-speech

I used the following code which shows Chrome supports SpeechSynthesisUtterance and the code works well on FireFox and Safari, but it is not working on Chrome (no sound). Why? Thank you.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type='text'></input>
            <select></select>
        </form>
        <script>
            
            if ( 'speechSynthesis' in window ) {
                var to_speak = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello world!');
                window.speechSynthesis.speak(to_speak);
            } else {
                alert('not support ');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/sharkdeng/pen/xxOVeqb

Comment: Try putting speechSynthesis.cancel(); before the speak command.

Comment: tried, still not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in Chrome speech synthasis requires user interaction before it speaks e.g. a button click.

I've added to your code to put the speak function behind the button's click event.

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if ( 'speechSynthesis' in window ) {
    const to_speak = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(input.value || 'Hello world!');
    speechSynthesis.cancel();
    speechSynthesis.speak(to_speak);
  } else {
    alert('not supported');
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='text' id="input"></input>
  <select id='voiceSelect'></select>
  <button type="button" id="button">Speak</button>
</form>
```